# How to style the width and height of amp-img

Tags: amp-html

Is it possible to style the width, height of amp-img?

A web page has lots of amp-img tags all of which have exactly the same width, height and layout. It would be nice to style them so that they do not have to be specified for each amp-img.

Tried the following:

```
 <style amp-custom>
    amp-img {
    vertical-align:top;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    }

    .bold{
    font-weight:bold
    }
 </style amp-custom>

   Tap
    <amp-img alt="Add" layout="fill" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/appbar.add.rest.png")"></amp-img>
    and choose one of the following actions:
```

It passes AMP validation, but the image does not show.  If layout="fill" is removed, the image shows, but it fails AMP validation.

Answer (score 3):

Not filling out anything (width, height or layout) forces AMP to assume the layout type is `container` which is not a supported layout type of `amp-img`. Therefore, at the minimum, you have you specify a layout. If you just want to specify a layout and then use CSS to specify width and height you can use `fill`.

You can then use CSS to reference `amp-img` and specify the width and height.

```
amp-img { width: 300px; height: 200px }
```

See the the `amp-img` [reference page](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-img) for more information regarding supported layouts.

> Supported Layouts:    fill, fixed, fixed-height, flex-item, intrinsic, nodisplay, responsive

To learn more about what each layout type means, check out the [layout and media queries](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/design/responsive/control_layout) document.

Comment: Thanks lot for helping out. The image does not show when I have <amp-img layout="fill" alt="Add" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/appbar.add.rest.png")"></amp-img>.  It shows up when I have layout="fixed", but it cannot pass validation.

Comment: Fill still requires dimension input from somewhere, whether it's the width and height attributes on the amp-img tag or set to the amp-img tag through CSS like in my example.

Comment: Yes, I set amp-img {
    vertical-align:top;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    }
but it does not show up though it passes AMP validation.

Comment: Try changing the double quotes inside the @url.content to be single quotes - they may be conflicting with the double quotes of the src attribute. I tried pasting in an image URL using your code and it worked fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178981/discussion-between-hong-and-craig-scott).